# Anchor tag offset with Bootstrap panels and fixed navbar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get anchor tags working properly with my Bootstrap setup with a fixed navbar. Since I have a fixed navbar, I am using the following CSS code to try and get the anchor tags (hash links) scrolling down to the right place:

```
.jumptarget:before { 
display: block; 
content: " "; 
margin-top: -60px; 
height: 60px; 
visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Then I am using `div`s with the jumptarget class assigned which hold my content. However, when I turn these `div`s into panels, the above css code stops working.

```
<div class="panel panel-default jumptarget" id="1">
<!-- random content here - this is the example that doesn't work -->
</div>
```

How can I use these panels and anchor tags together. Also, if I encase my panels in `div`s with just the `anchortag`class and the relevant `id` it messes up the display of my website. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Anchor links (navigating to content on the same page) works with IDs, unless you're using Javascript not included in your question.

This example works:

http://jsbin.com/xivecaz/2/edit?html,css,output

Note: I have added dummy content above and below to allow the page to scroll to demonstrate the navigation.